# Access ViewState variables with Ajax call Static Method

Tags: jquery, ajax

New to Ajax and here's a question.

The Aspx page has a grid view (with sorting allowed). Below the grid is a dropdownlist with page no.s. User can select a number to go to that page. At initial page load, the grid shows records, with column - 'OrderId' sorted in 'desc' order.
The current sorted order and the name of this column are stored as ViewState variables. When any column is sorted, these variables are updated.

The stored procedure to get the data, accepts columnName, SortOrder, PageNo. and Page size as parameters.

This code is working fine. Now, I would like to use this with an Ajax call. If changed to 'public static', it cannot access the ViewState variables.

So, please guide me how I can use this function with Ajax.
If it is only possible that the ColumnName & sortOrder should be sent as parameters from the Ajax function, then how to do that.

```
private void BindOrders(int index)
 {
  int pageSize = 10;

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetOrderDetails", con);                
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortOrder", ViewState["vSortDirection"]
                              .ToString());
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColName", ViewState["vSortExpression"]
                               .ToString());
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartIndex", index);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", pageSize);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = 
                     ParameterDirection.Output;
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  con.Open();
  da.Fill(dt);
  con.Close();

  int rowcount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Value);

  if (rowcount > 0)
   {
    gvOrders.DataSource = dt;
    gvOrders.DataBind();

    int n = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)rowcount / (decimal)pageSize);
    ddlPage.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     {
      ddlPage.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));                        
     }

    ddlPage.SelectedIndex = index - 1;
  }            
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already on ASP.NET, there is an `UpdatePanel` that let's you do Ajax. It will prevent full page reloads.

Comment: I know about the update panel. But I would like to try it this way. Also, is it the same when using an updatepanel and making an Ajax call, I mean the response times etc?

Comment: Sort of, under the hood Ajax remains Ajax. ASP.NET just adds more bloat to the solution. You could hack up your own, but I think it will be very painful and you won't gain much from the experience other than learning how `UpdatePanel` works under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Could you plz confirm, what I am trying to acheive, is it possible, without using UpdatePanel?

Comment: Of course! I was actually trying to hack up a solution to your question myself until I remembered UpdatePanel. The main problem I think you are going to have is learning the idiosyncrasies of ASP.NET in the rendered HTML (ViewState eventually ends up getting stuffed somewhere in HTML). The second problem you will have and the reason I don't recommend this is that the HTML may change with subsequent upgrades to the ASP.NET framework. I never recommend locking yourself in to any version of any technology.